# A custom proxy yields Incompatible magic value 1012089682

Tags: http, reverse-proxy

I have a custom http proxy that one worked. I have made some changes to its authentication process. And now when I try to launch an applet I get "Incompatible magic value 1012089682 in class file ...". Regular html files are transferred without any errors.

In my other web research I found this article http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=313827 discussing an ascii vs binary transfer issue.

My problem with debugging this is that the get of the jar file doesn't show up in tamper data on the browser nor in the access log of the webserver containing the proxy, nor in my proxy error log. So I am some what baffled. any help in how to get more information to solve this would be appreciated.

The technology is antique, but the company doesn't want to pay for upgrades. The proxy is an NSAPI plugin running in IWS 6 (SunOne webserver)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was indeed a bug in my proxy code. I am not exactly sure what caused the symptoms described above, but fixing the code so that it didn't re-authenticate every time fixed my issue.